# Conditional formatting Excel 2010, as per attached sheet how can I apply conditional formatting in column b?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excellibrary

```
10  9
20  10
30  25
40  18
50  27
60  50
70  55
80  40
90  30
100 150
```

I want conditional formatting in Column `b Colosseum` less the a column

[image]

Comment: like for range B1:B10 conditional formatting formula:`=B1<A1`???

Comment: Wow, this is just rude..

Answer (score -1):

Another way !!!

Step 1

Select cell b1 and then goto 'highlight cell rules' under conditional formatting, and select 'less then '

Step 2

Select cell A1 and remove the dollar signs or enter =A1 manually, hit ok. Copy and paste cell b1 formatting in  range b2:b10 using paste special command